# Why not use fewer lines of code in this function (urllib.urlopen)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working through a tutorial for beginner's level python, and I found that I can get the same result with one less line of code, and I don't know why the instructor (he is a professional for 15+ years) chose to do it with an additional line/variable. My assumption is that it either has to do with low-level use of the `urllib` library, and/or it may be programming best-practices, but I'm hoping someone might be able to tell me why.

The function in question is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def load_page(url: str):
    response = urlopen(url)
    html = response.read().decode('utf')
    return html
```

As I've learned, this returns the actual HTML of the request. But while I was debugging and just inspecting what each piece of that function does/returns, I found that I can get the same result (the HTML of the request) by removing the "response" variable completely:

```
def load_page(url: str):
    html = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf')
    return html
```

Is there a reason you would want to first assign `urlopen(url)` to `response`, instead of just running `read()` and `decode()` directly on `urlopen(url)`?

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to reduce the function's length by one line?

Comment: The same reason why you've also chosen to assign to `html` and not return the decoded output directly.

Comment: It's simply for clarity and readability.

Comment: Think of it a bit like math homework. It can be easier to follow when you show your workings.

Comment: Following your logic of brevity you could eliminate the function and just put one line of code in your program `html = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf')`

Comment: @BrenBarn I was thinking with efficiency and compute-cost in mind. Obviously this is a tiny example and doesn't make much difference, but as I'm looking ahead to when I'll work on much larger applications, I want to think with efficiency in mind. (I almost mentioned that, but chose not to include it in my question)

Comment: @triplethreatguy: There is no difference in compute cost because the same operations are being done in both cases.

Comment: It is doubtful that there would be any difference, but you can look at the byte code generated using `dis` https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html to make sure.  The computer does not execute python code, it is there for our convenience - so we might as well make it as convenient as we can.  When code breaks we need to fix it fast, obfuscated code slows the debug/repair cycle, even though it might be the same (or faster) to execute.

Comment: By the way, as an ex-instructor myself, your instructor might relish the chance to have this discussion.  I'm sure he will agree with the posts here.

Comment: I'd recommend saying `.decode('utf-8')` for readability, `utf` is an alias for `utf-8` in python but there exist other encodings named similarly (utf-16 and others).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like functions should "do one thing" the same could be said about each line of code. There has been a similar question (about the broader concept of reducing line count on [Software Engineering: "Is fewer lines of code always better?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203684/is-fewer-lines-of-code-always-better))

It's one operation to make the request, one operation to get the contents of the request.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def load_page(url: str):
    response = urlopen(url)               # make request
    html = response.read().decode('utf')  # get contents
    return html
```

This has a number of advantages:

- Debugging: If it fails you know where it fails (in terms of line number). Did it fail when doing the `urlopen` or when `decode`?
- Extending the code: You also want to inspect the `status` of the response or the `header`? Easy, just access `response.status` or `response.headers`.
- Readability: The more operations/calls there are in one line the harder it is to immediately understand what the line is doing.

However in this case it would be "acceptable" to do the `read().decode(...)` in the return line:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def load_page(url: str):
    response = urlopen(url)               # make request
    return response.read().decode('utf')  # get contents and return
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation is very helpful! I think this all may become much more obvious to me in the future, when I get into much longer and more complex code; however, your explanation, especially of debugging and extending the code, make perfect sense to me. Additionally, as others mentioned, readability certainly is something to keep in mind as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

MXeifert's answer is very good. I would focus on one point in particular:

> Readability

As stated more operations/calls on a single line makes it harder to understand.
This is not just because it is more compressed but also because it limits your ability to describe the situation. This is very similar to using bad variable names, consider the following:

```
x = ShowPanel()
print(x)
```

ShowPanel() in this case doesn't seem to be a great function name. But if we are unable to change that name then we should use our variable to make the code describe itself more effectively. We don't need to do this and we could just do this:

```
print(ShowPanel())
```

But i still have no idea what is going to be printed. What about:

```
isPanelVisible = ShowPanel()
print(isPanelVisible)
```

better.

The same is true in your example

```
html = response.read().decode('utf')
return html
```

vs

```
return response.read().decode('utf')
```

The first very clearly shows that html is being returned. The second, while still not overly complicated is not as clear.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that's a great addition to why readability is important, especially in this and similar examples where we are specifying what is being returned.